# stuck on with input validation in c++ either string or integer

Tags: c++, validation, input, console

I am trying to practice my input validation in C++. How can i let the program validate the user input when a user is asked to enter a number or string?
Here is a sample of my code.

```
public:
void CreateProduct() {
inputProduct:
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\tPLEASE PROVIDE ACCURATE INFORMATION";
    cout << "\n\n\t\tPRODUCT NUMBER: ";
    cin >> ProductNumber;
    if (!cin) {
        cout << "\nPlease provide an integer";
        cin.clear();
        cin.end;
        goto inputProduct;
       //when enter a string i should enter this if statement and exit
       // to be asked for another entry but am getting stuck in a loop.
    }
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\tPRODUCT NAME: ";
    cin >> ProductName;
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\tPRICE: ";
    cin >> Price;
    system("cls");

}
```

Please help me understand this input validation.

Comment: What do you not understand in particular?

Comment: If its an integer entry it shouldnt accept text or strings.

Comment: You mean it doesn't skip the `if (!cin) { ...` if you input an integer number?

Comment: It does skip but if its not an integer it gets stuck in a loop.

Comment: @WillieMwewa get rid of the `goto` and use a `do - while` loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can check whether input is number or not by checking ascii value of each character in input .

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    std::string str;

    std::cin>>str;

    bool isNumeric = true;
    for(size_t i=0;i<str.length();++i)
    {
        if(str[i]< '0' || str[i] > '9')
        {
           isNumeric = false;
          break;
        }
    }

    if(!isNumeric)
    {
        std::cout<<"Input is not an integer";
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```